# Timeout only when connecting through Management console

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL server 2008r2 on a windows 2003 server and connecting to it from a vista machine.

The database itself is part of an application that uses ODBC to connect and that connects perfectly 100% of the time.

But as I'm making some changes to the application and database I'm working through the management console. The first time I try and connect to the db in the morning it times out.

I have a work around for it that involves remote desktoping to the server and connecting to the db using the mamangement console on the same server. Once I have connected locally I can close the remote session and then I'll be able to connect to the server from the management console on my pc. This connection will stay open all day but if I close the management console for a while (10+ mins, I havent fully tested how long) it will timeout again.

This happens from other client pcs as well so I'm thinking that I need to change something on the server... does anyone have any pointers as to what settings could cause this login timeout? and what I can do to fix it as its becoming a serious annoyance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have got it figured out now. The solution that seems to work is linked to TCP/IP protocol, as the above poster mentions. I needed to go into the protocol and update the ports used from dynamic to fixed and put them on 1433 (why this isn't default I dont know, and I presume theres good reason for it!)

Answer found on the post below

https://serverfault.com/questions/179898/sql-server-timeout-on-first-attempt

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to enable TCP/IP protocol.  You can do this via SSCM (SQL Server Configuration Manager).

Comment: TCP/IP is enabled for the server. In fact we have it set so that shared memory, tcp/ip and pipes are all enabled, just via is disabled (not sure why its this way tbh). I've tried using different connections types through odbc and they all work fine - not sure how i can change the connection type for the management console though